# Create Data-Structure from text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, data-structures

I have a file that looks like this:

```
User -> Artist
u1 -> a1
u1 -> a15
u1 -> a123
u2 -> a1
u2 -> a32
...
u1800 -> a56
```

which tells us which artists every user has listened to.

How can I import this in a two-dimensional array (or maybe another more appropriate data-structure?) in which every row will be a user and every [row][column] one of the artists the user has listened to?

I want to end up storing that `u1` has listened to `{a1, a15, a123}` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store this information in a `Map`. Suppose you have an `User` class and an `Artist` class, you could create a `Map<User, Set<Artist>>` that would keep a set (or list if you prefer) of artists for each user.

To create the map you do:

```
Map<User, Set<Artist>> artistsFromUser = new HashMap<>();
```

If you just need to store the usernames and artist names as strings, your map can be:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> artistsFromUser = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you will need to run through your file, transforming each `user -> artist` pair into an `user` object and an `artist` object. After that, you can store the `artist` using the corresponding `user` reference:

```
// Retrieve the set of artists for this user
// Substitute String for Artist here if you're just storing the names
Set<Artist> artists = artistsFromUser.get(user);
if (artists == null) {
    // If the set was not created for this user yet
    // you need to create it and store it in the map
    artists = new HashSet<>();
    artistsFromUser.put(user, artists);
}
// Add the new artist to the set
artists.add(artist);
```

Printing your output would be as simple as doing:

```
System.out.println(user + " has listened to " + artistsFromUser.get(user));
```

Answer (score 2):

Having read your file into a `List<String>`, it's a one-liner:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = lines.stream()
    .map(s -> s.split(" -> "))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0]))
    .entries().stream()
    .toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .map(a -> a[1]).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Code thumbed in on phone - may contain syntax errors</sup>

Comment: @apgp88 yes. this is a java 8 solution. Java 8 has been out for a year now, so java 8 is the mainstream version now

Answer (score 0):

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) `Multimap` is the exact structure for this. A [`Multimap<K, V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is conceptually the same as a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, which is what you want.

In particular, a [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) would be ideal for your case. You could use a mix of Guava & Java 8 to satisfy your requirements:

```
public class FileParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Path to file
        Path path = Paths.get("fileparser-test.txt");

        // Process file line by line, skipping first
        // one and splitting to get user and artist
        Iterator<String[]> splittedLinesIterator = 
                Files.lines(path).skip(1).
                map(s -> s.split(" -> ")).iterator();

        // Create multimap, indexing by the first element of array
        ListMultimap<String, String[]> multimap = 
                Multimaps.index(splittedLinesIterator, s -> s[0]);

        // Transform values by only keeping second element of array
        ListMultimap<String, String> result = 
                Multimaps.transformValues(multimap, s -> s[1]);

        System.out.println(result); // {u1=[a1, a15, a123], u2=[a1, a32]}
    }
}
```

Please see [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), [`Multimaps.index()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) and [`Multimaps.transformValues()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#transformValues(com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) docs for further reference.